# Dart wrong calculation in sum

Tags: dart, numbers, double

Can someone explain to me why the following sum gives wrong result in dart?

```
final double result = 90071992547409.9 + 0.01;
print(result);
```

It prints the number 90071992547409.92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Dart documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.0/dart-core/double-class.html):

> Dart doubles are 64-bit floating-point numbers as specified in the IEEE 754 standard.

It's because of [floating-point arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/). In your case (I used [this converter](https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/)):

90071992547409.9 = 90071992547409.90625 ~= **90071992547409.91**

0.01 = 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375 ~= **0.01**

90071992547409.91 + 0.01 = **90071992547409.92**

The best solution in dart is to use the [decimal](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal) package.